# how do i pull data from a website in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services

i'm trying to make a program in vb.net that needs to pull information on a certain topic from websites like Wikipedia and wolfram alpha and i cant seem to find how to do this any where.
i would like to store the information found in an Xml file for easy access later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

That's what you're going to need, there is plenty of documentation if you do a google search on it.